# Jquery get JSON value of an object where key value equals ID variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Okay, I've found many similar threads, but can't seem to find exactly what I need. I believe I'm missing something obvious, but I'm a JSON noob, so please help me out.

On click I'm getting an ID and storing it as a variable. Then I want to find a JSON object inside "messageString" where msgstring = ID. and then display the subject of that message in #convo-title.

Here's my JSON:

```
{
"messageString":[
{
  "subject":"This is the message subject",
  "msgstring":"001",
  "attach":"shop-cart",
  "message":[
     {
        "date-time":"June 2, 2013 12:22 pm",
        "rec-name":"D. Craig",
        "mbr-href":"#craig",
        "msg-content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
     },
     {
        "date-time":"June 3, 2013 12:22 pm",
        "rec-name":"N. McCoy",
        "mbr-href":"#mccoy",
        "msg-content": "Vestibulum ultricies odio semper."
     }
  ]
},
{
  "subject":"This is a great subject",
  "msgstring":"002",
  "attach":"shop-cart",
  "message":[
     {
        "date-time":"June 2, 2013 12:22 pm",
        "rec-name":"D. Craig",
        "mbr-href":"#craig",
        "msg-content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
     }
  ]
},
{
  "subject":"Interested in your tomatoes",
  "msgstring":"003",
  "attach":"shop-cart",
  "message":[
     {
        "date-time":"June 4, 2013 12:22 pm",
        "rec-name":"J. Smith",
        "mbr-href":"#smith",
        "msg-content": "Vestibulum vitae turpis sodales, pellentesque elit in, lobortis nisl."
     },
     {
        "date-time":"June 5, 2013 12:22 pm",
        "rec-name":"B. Wardlaw",
        "mbr-href":"#wardlaw",
        "msg-content": "Nunc pretium dictum justo sed luctus."
     }
  ]
}
]}
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
$('#conv-nav li').live('click', function () {
var id = $(this).attr('id');

$.getJSON('data/msg.json', {
        msgstring: id
}, function (data) {
        $('.string.msg').empty();
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var title = item.subject;
                $('#convo-title').empty();
                $('#convo-title').text(title);
        });
 });
});
```

I've verified that I am getting the ID and in firebug I do see it getting the JSON file with the parameter of the id. #convo-title empties as it should but then the new title doesn't get inserted.

No errors are showing in firebug.

HELP!! I'd appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(item)` (right before or after your `var title = item.subject`)?

Comment: Hmm.. even though the parameters are being passed it appears it's returning all the objects:
[Object { subject="This is the message subject", msgstring="001", attach="shop-cart", more...}, Object { subject="This is a great subject", msgstring="002", attach="shop-cart", more...}, Object { subject="Interested in your tomatoes", msgstring="003", attach="shop-cart", more...}]

Comment: Note that, unless you use the parameter `msgstring` server side to filter your JSON data explicitly, it will return all records. A JSON file fetched from the server will not be filtered.

Comment: Okay, so even if it returns all records is there a way I can simply display only the subject of the record I'm after?

Comment: I would recommend that you _do_ implement server side filtering. Otherwide you download a big JSON file with each click.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are iterating over the data, but the first record is messageString, and you need to iterate over the *contents* of messageString.

So, based on your json, it would appear that this section:

```
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var title = item.subject;
            $('#convo-title').empty();
            $('#convo-title').text(title);
    });
```

Should look like this:

```
    $.each(data.messageString, function (i, item) {
            var title = item.subject;
            $('#convo-title').empty();
            $('#convo-title').text(title);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that. It doesn't empty #convo-title then. :( When I add that in and add console.log(item) to your solution I see this:

    Object { subject="This is the message subject", msgstring="001", attach="shop-cart", more...}
Object { subject="This is a great subject", msgstring="002", attach="shop-cart", more...}
Object { subject="Interested in your tomatoes", msgstring="003", attach="shop-cart", more...}